# How to forcing Powershell to use new Azure Subscription

Tags: powershell, azure

I have two subscription one with old cloud service and other is with new cloud service. I am using Powershell to access my new subscription. I have downloaded latest .publishsettings and set it using Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile. My problem is that I always get the old subscription set and could not figureout how to force powershell to use my new subscription.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With new Powershell commands you would need to set which particular subscription you would want to use. The steps are as below:

1. **Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile *yourpublishsettings*.publishsettings**
2. **Get-AzureSubscription** (this will give you the list of subscription)
3. **Select-AzureSubscription _select_subscription_name** (this way you can set which particular subscription you want to use)

This should work!!

Comment: This does not seam to persist between sessions... how do you change it perminantly

Comment: out of data for AzureRM

Answer (score 8):

Just to clarify, there are two kinds of 'special' subscriptions, the 'current' subscription (which is the subscription used for any command in the current PowerShell session), and the Defaul subscription, which is the subscription used even after the current PowerShell session ends.

using `Select-AzureSubscription <subscription-name>` will set the current subscription.  If you'd like to change the subscription across sessions, use `Select-AzureSubscription -Default <subscription name>`

Comment: I have found that -default does not persist across sessions

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for the classic Azure management. If you're on the new ARM then you want to do something like

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Get-AzureRmSubscription
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId blah
```

where blah is the subscription ID from the second command